# assign a user a role from admin creates a user, in Yii Rbac extension Rights

Tags: php, yii, rights, rbac, yii-extensions

I have installed rights as suggested by most people, its easy to implement Role based access control. but I am stuck at a problem..

I need to assign a user a role from admin, who can change their roles..etc..

As rights doesn't create models for the tables I cant insert in them..and as such there is no documentation, how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a drop-down of all roles in the system, for admin to select..

```
<?php
if (Yii::app()->user->isSuperuser) {
       $all_roles=new RAuthItemDataProvider('roles', array( 
    'type'=>2,
    ));
      $data=$all_roles->fetchData();
?>
    <div>
        <label for="type_id">Type</label>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList("Type",'',CHtml::listData($data,'name','name'));?    > 
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

And then on backend you'll need to asign a role to the user based on the Type values selected by the admin...

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isSuperuser)
    $type=$_POST['Type'];
else
    $type='User';

$authorizer = Yii::app()->getModule("rights")->authorizer;
$authorizer->authManager->assign($type, $model->id);
```

This code checks if the registration was from admin, then it sets the role selected by the admin, else it sets `User` as role, ie, same code will work for `admin user create and normal signup`..

There are such other issues in Rights which are not preperly documented...I have written some in my blog..
[My blog post about Yii Rights](http://octathorpeweb.com/blog/2012/03/06/yii-rights-extension-rbac-role-based-access-control/)

Answer (score 2):

Well that is actually Yii and not rights

```
Yii::app()->authManager->assign($role, $userid);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IAuthManager#assign-detail

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Rights - I use [rbam](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rbam) extension instead. Have you tried to search your answer in [Rights manual](http://yii-rights.googlecode.com/files/yii-rights-doc-1.2.0.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($user->save())
    Rights::assign('Authenticated', $user->id);
```

*"Authenticated" can be replaced with any other role.*